# Abort due to constraint violation columns C1,C2,C3 are not unique

Tags: sqlite

I have a composite primary key(C1+C2+C3)on a table.
Here is the DDL

```
    CREATE TABLE "InputFiles" (
  [PlantID] INTEGER, 
  [FileID] INTEGER, 
  [VesselDataCase] CHAR(9), 
  [Comments] CHAR(73),  
Primary key([PlantID], [FileID]),
  FOREIGN KEY(PlantId) REFERENCES Plant(PlantId) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE [VesselData] (
[MaterialType] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
[Operating_Temperature] NUMERIC, 
  [IRTndt] numeric, 
  [VDID] integer, 
  [PlantId] integer, 
  [FileId] integer,
FOREIGN KEY([plantid], [fileid]) REFERENCES [inputfiles]([plantid], [fileid]) ON DELETE cascade, 
  CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_VesselData_1] PRIMARY KEY ([VDID], [PlantId], [FileId])); 

When I try to insert a new row in VesselData Table
```

Suppose VDID = 1, Fileid = 2, Plantid = 3. So it looks for(1+2+3) combination. 
Even though fields with these values dont exist in the Table, it gives me 
Abort due to constraint violation
columns VDID, PlantId, FileId are not unique SQlite exception

But, it is inserting the field in the table. After inserting this field it gives me this exception. Either it shouldn't insert or abort due to invalid field values

Thank you
Sun

Comment: Is there a reason why all of your column names are in brackets?